# Find dark/light colors of theme

Tags: android, colors, material-design, android-color

What are the default colors for a dark or light theme?

What I'm looking for is following:

**Light theme - derived from https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-system**

```
* Primary:          Indigo 500
* Primary Dark:     Indigo 700
* Accent:           Pink A200
```

**Dark theme**

```
* Primary:          Indigo ?
* Primary Dark:     Indigo ?
* Accent:           Pink ?
```

I think the light theme is correct as it's derived from the link but what are the default values for the dark theme? What is an example of correct dark theme colors?

**Goal**

The goal is to derive the correct combination of colors for a green theme. Like light theme is Green500/Green900/RedA200 and dark theme is ??? (I don't know which colors are considered perfectly fitting together here).

Comment: what exactly want?

Comment: I want to know the default colors for the light and dark material theme... I think that's clear?

Comment: u want darkActionbar theme color? and light action bar ? right?

Comment: No. `primaryColor`, `primaryColorDark` and `accentColor` are all I'm interested in

Comment: which theme color u want in android

Comment: The default theme color (blue and pink). Based on this theme I'm interested the 6 colors (3 for the light and 3 for the dark theme)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146648/discussion-between-kevan-aghera-and-prom85).

Answer (score 1):

> The goal is to derive the correct combination of colors for my green theme. Like light theme is Green500/Green900/RedA200 and dark theme is ??? (I don't know which colors are considered perfectly fitting together here).

[*Material Design Color Tool*](https://material.io/color) is the tool you need. It will prompt with light and dark colors of specified gamma.

[image]

Comment: I've seen that page and tried it, still I'm not sure how to find material confirm combinations. I edited my question a little bit. I'm not sure if I should use Green500/Green700/OrangeA200 for a dark theme (the same values I would use for the light theme) or maybe Green400/Green600/OrangeA300 or whatever. I'm not sure what is considered as correct material confirm theme and I've not found a single example for a dark theme yet...